# When adding controller unable to get metadata mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to create my first mvc class and am having an issue getting started.
I am using a shared database on my hosting account and have created the following class

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class tUsers
    {

            public int UserID { get; set; }
            public string Username { get; set; }
            public string UserEmail { get; set; }
            public string UserPassword { get; set; }
            public int GroupId { get; set; }


    }

    public class tUsersDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<tUsers> tUsers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is my connection string

```
   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=gdfgdfgdfg;Initial Catalog=fsdf_fdsf;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ddd_reddntal;Password=fgfggfdg" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

the error i get is

> Unable to retrieve metadata for 'mvcapplication2.models.tusers' one or
>   more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Entity type users has no defended key.

Also do my model names need to match my table names exact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entity Framework can not identify the primary key property of your `tUsers` class. Annotate `UserID` property with `Key` attribute. If your table name is different from the class name use the `Table` attribute to specify the table name.

Try to use proper naming conventions for class names. In this case it should be `User` not `tUsers`.

```
[Table("MyTableName")]
public class tUsers
{       
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public string UserPassword { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It can automatically find your primary key if you name the column Id instead of UserId, but personally I never use it, just to let you know

Comment: this worked great but now i am getting the following error CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have defined Id as Primary key in your Table and also Make sure you have properly defined properties for your Model Class. Also Please add your proper connection string to config file in addition to DefaultConnection provided by application. I hope this will help.

Thanks